# In ruby what does "$$" mean?

Tags: ruby

In my rails console:

```
$$
#=> 12680
```

in IRB in other tab:

```
$$
#=> 15550
```

What does `$$` stands for in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [google-fu](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) shows me that `$$` is the process number of the Ruby running the script.

Comment: Having google-fu is easily achievable and needs to be exercised at every opportunity. Simply typing in `ruby $$` in the Google search box immediately pops down and reveals `"ruby $$ pid"` which results in the information you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

From "[Ruby Programming/Syntax/Variables and Constants](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables)":

```
$$ - $PROCESS_ID, $PID or Process.pid - The process number of the Ruby running this script.
```

Comment: It's very important to clearly specify where your source is if you're quoting from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I made a wild guess it was can be process it. I validated it with

```
Process.pid
#=> returns the same value as $$
```

PS: if there's more to it, please care to add your answer or comment.